# How to override the "get-childItem" command in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Could I override this command? I want to do my own job when I execute the "Get-ChildItem" command in Powershell.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? We can help you better if we know what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm try to simulate some powershell command provided by other company(XenDesktop), and all of the other commands have already been simulated, but at the last of the task, I found one of the command, "Get-ChildItem", is the command provided by powershell itself, I want to know could I override it.

Comment: For example, XenDesktop provides a "Get-ConfigSite" powershell command, and I have no idea about the logical of the command script, but I know the result of it, so I will add the same name "Get-ConfigSite.ps1" file in my compute, and in the file, I will use powershell script to create the simulated result. All of the task work well, until I met the "get-childitem" command, which is provided by powershell, that means it already exsits in my computer,  so I want to override it, or how can I let powershell use my script when I execute "Get-ChildItem" command.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can override `Get-ChildItem` or any other cmdlet in Powershell.

### Name Your Function The Same

If you make a function with the same name in the same scope, yours will be used.

Example:

```powershell
Function Get-ChildItem {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    # Simulate the parameters here
)
    # ... do stuff
}
```

### Using Aliases

Create your own function, and then create an alias to that function, with the same name as the cmdlet you want to override.

Example:

```powershell
Function My-GetChildItem {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    # Simulate the parameters here
)
    # ... do stuff
}

New-Alias -Name 'Get-ChildItem' -Value 'My-GetChildItem' -Scope Global
```

This way is nice because it's easier to test your function without stomping on the built-in function, and you can control when the cmdlet is overridden or not within your code.

To remove the alias:

```powershell
Remove-Item 'Alias:\Get-ChildItem' -Force
```

### Know the Command Precedence

[about_Command_Precedence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848304.aspx) lists the order in which commands of different types are interpreted:

> If you do not specify a path, Windows PowerShell uses the following
>            precedence order when it runs commands:
>
> 1. Alias
> 2. Function
> 3. Cmdlet
> 4. Native Windows commands

Comment: Thanks @briantist, I have solved it using the first solution. I created a profile.ps1 at the path of $pshome and I add my functions in it, so that every session will load this profile, also load my functions. It works fine in the local situation, but when I used remote powershell to connect to my computer, these functions cannot be invoked, and a CommnadNotFoundException was thrown. Do you know the reason of it?

Comment: By the way, does you mean add a function to the profile.ps1 when you said "Name the function the same", since I noticed the syntax is not the same with my function definition in profile.ps1.